# C++ How to use std::function and std::bind with a member function with default parameters and custom object parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, functor, std-function, stdbind

I am attempting to write a wrapper class for an Async Physics query function with a return type and many function parameters, some of which have default values. The wrapper class will help maintain an internal state of the async query, thread data, and other important meta-data, which makes it easier to use for engineers. Below is the UWorld function and the typedef I created to represent it:

```
FTraceHandle    UWorld::AsyncOverlapByObjectType(const FVector& Pos, const FQuat& Rot, const FCollisionObjectQueryParams& ObjectQueryParams, const FCollisionShape& CollisionShape, const FCollisionQueryParams& Params = FCollisionQueryParams::DefaultQueryParam, FOverlapDelegate * InDelegate = NULL, uint32 UserData = 0) { ... }

typedef std::function<FTraceHandle( const FVector&, const FQuat&, const FCollisionObjectQueryParams&, const FCollisionShape&, const FCollisionQueryParams&, FOverlapDelegate*, uint32 )> AsyncOverlapByObjectTypeFunction;
```

In my AsyncHelperFile.h, I have the following typedef and class:

```
typedef std::function<FTraceHandle( const FVector&, const FQuat&, const FCollisionObjectQueryParams&, const FCollisionShape&, const FCollisionQueryParams&, FOverlapDelegate*, uint32 )> AsyncOverlapByObjectTypeFunction;

/**
 * Helper class for Async collisions
 */
class AsyncCollision_OverlapByObjectType
{
public:
   AsyncCollision_OverlapByObjectType();

   // Use this CTOR if there are multiple Worlds and you want to specify the world context.
   // If no context is provided, then the StrayKiteAsyncCollision is used
   explicit AsyncCollision_OverlapByObjectType( UWorld* const contextOverride );

   ~AsyncCollision_OverlapByObjectType();



   FORCEINLINE const bool HasQueryPending() { return ( CurrentTraceHandle._Data.FrameNumber != StrayKiteAsyncCollision::InvalidFrameNumber ); }

   FORCEINLINE FOverlapDelegate& GetOverlapDelegate() { return OverlapDelegate; }
   FORCEINLINE FTraceHandle      GetTraceHandle() const { return CurrentTraceHandle; }

   void Reset();

private:
   // Called from CTOR's
   FORCEINLINE void SetOverlapQueryForWorldContext( UWorld* const worldContext )
   {
      CurrentWorldContext                 = CurrentWorldContext;
      AsyncOverlapByObjectType            = std::bind( &UWorld::AsyncOverlapByObjectType, worldContext, const FVector&, const FQuat&, const FCollisionObjectQueryParams&, const FCollisionShape&, const FCollisionQueryParams&, FOverlapDelegate*, uint32 );
   }


   AsyncOverlapByObjectTypeFunction                                              AsyncOverlapByObjectType;
   FOverlapDatum                                                                 OverlapDatum;
   FOverlapDelegate                                                              OverlapDelegate;
   FTraceHandle                                                                  CurrentTraceHandle;
   TWeakObjectPtr<UWorld>                                                        CurrentWorldContext;
};
```

Since most of my C++ experience is Pre-C++11, I am not that familiar with std::function and std::bind. I am struggling to find good examples of how to use this pair together to bind a complex member function ptr with a return type.

The current compile error I am receiving is **error C2059: syntax error: 'const** on line 99, which is this snippet:

```
AsyncOverlapByObjectType = std::bind( &UWorld::AsyncOverlapByObjectType, worldContext, const FVector&, const FQuat&, const FCollisionObjectQueryParams&, const FCollisionShape&, const FCollisionQueryParams&, FOverlapDelegate*, uint32 );

// Update - or is this the correct way to use bind? This does compile but
// conceptually I don't understand what the placeholders are doing here
AsyncOverlapByObjectType = std::bind( &UWorld::AsyncOverlapByObjectType, worldContext, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, 
             std::placeholders::_3, std::placeholders::_4, std::placeholders::_5, std::placeholders::_6, std::placeholders::_7 );
```

What do I need to do to use these std library functions in conjunction together so that I may bind a std::function object to the UWorld::AsyncOverlapByObjectType function? Conceptually, am I missing a core concept here for their use? My current guess is it is not working due to how I am using std::bind. Does std::bind need dummy arguments for all the possible function parameters in UWorld::AsyncOverlapByObjectType? Any conceptual explanation of how these work together would be helpful.

Comment: Post C++11, you'd want lambdas.

Comment: I cannot use lambdas for this use-case. It is against coding standards. Also, on a personal preference level, I prefer to avoid lambdas unless it is absolutely required. I find them to make it more difficult to parse code

Comment: bind more readable than lambdas? It takes a bit to get used to new syntax, but the only way to get used to it is to use it ;)

Comment: I am open to using other methods than std::function or std::bind. I explored using a Functor but found quite a bit of difficulty setting it up properly.  The common issue I run into seems to be the Default Parameters

Comment: would be good if you could create a [mcve]. Something more minimal. Your function signature and the line with the error fills 3 screen widths, when I am sure you can make a simpler example with the same error. What is the issue with default parameters? What default parameters?

Comment: I just added the UWorld::AsyncOverlapByObjectType signature and the default parameters it uses

Comment: @idclev463035818 if I switch the std::bind call to std::bind( &UWorld::AsyncOverlapByObjectType, worldContext, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, std::placeholders::_3, std::placeholders::_4, std::placeholders::_5, std::placeholders::_6, std::placeholders::_7 ); , it compiles. But, is this a correct setup?

Comment: `const FVector&` doesnt make sense as parameter to `bind`. I dont understand what you expect that to do (mainly because your code example is unreadable for me, please create a simpler mcve)

Comment: @idclev463035818 In essence, all I am trying to accomplish it to create a reference to the UWorld member function and invoke it with a UWorld* when a query is submitted

Comment: I can only repeat. Your code is unreadable for me. For example  I cannot see the type and the name of your members at the same time and I am not even sure if I need to see them to understand the problem

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Lambdas more difficult than bind()? I doubt that. There's literally one thing that weirds people about lambdas and it's the capture clause. It is otherwise just a functor, minus all the needless setup. I find it absolutely backwards that your coding standard would allow a homespun functor, but not lambdas which have been a core language feature for 9 years now.

Comment: Yes, you have found the correct solution (assuming you insist on using `std::bind`). Use placeholders for parameters you want to leave unbound.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik When you mention unbound, you mean the param value can be changed when function is called? Also, what other alternatives are there to bind other than Lambas?

Comment: By "unbound" I mean parameters for which you still have to supply arguments when calling the object returned by `std::bind`. As to other alternatives - well, you could hand-craft a "normal" named class with an overloaded `operator()` that would work the same way as the result of `std::bind`, or a lambda expression, would. These language facilities merely automate creation of such classes, but you can create one the hard way if you insist.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you for the explanation. Sometimes its a trickier balancing act on choosing what method than just preference. Since this code must run on over 5 different Operating Systems and different C++ compilers, I don't always have all the options available. I can see why bind looks overly complicated. I merely wanted to understand its use. I am open to trying different methods.